# Persistent localStroage variable after refresh in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage

I am trying to keep track of the state of some values through LocalStorage. I initialize it in a service and use / modify it accordingly in the controller, using set and get functions.
The problem is when the page gets reloaded. This is why initially I decided to use localStorage in the first place. Since I initialize the variable inside the service, every time the page is reloaded, so is the value of the variable in the localStorage.

my service:

```
AuthService.$inject = ['$q', '$http', 'LocalStorage', 'CONFIG'];
function AuthService($q, $http, LocalStorage, CONFIG) {
    LocalStorage.set("isloggedin", false);
});
```

Since this was only to test the usage of local storage, I am only initializing and printing the value, so I really don't think that some other piece of code is responsible that the variable becomes false.

I also tried using root scope (despite the many advises not to), and would prefer not to try anything else until I've got the thing with local storage figured out. So is there any way to make the value in local storage persistent?

Comment: Not certain what issue is? Does `LocalStorage` reference `window.localStorage`?

Comment: Do you really need to use an angular module for this? It's built in Javascritp and no external library should be needed. Localstorage is persistent however each browser acts different, Mozilla implements it like a cookie and Chrome as Cache for example. Saying that, you should not heavily depend on localstorage, nor you should store any sensitive information as it can be easily manipulated from client level.

Comment: @Adriani6 I am playing around with an existing ionic project for mobile applications. While it contained a good structure, there was no functionality at all. And I am not going to lie and say that I understand what everything does exactly, but it was interesting so I am trying to build some basic features in it. The (little existing) logic already works with angular js. However, I would appreciate any alternative suggestions on how to store for example the login status, or other data that need to be persistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i really hate to figure out an answer 5 minutes after posting the question and I still am not sure that this is the correct answer, or the most efficient solution. But here is what I did and it worked.

Initial declaration of the local storage variable apparently is not necessary in angular js. You just set the values whenever you need them and they will continue even after a reload.

Anyway, as a total newbie, I would welcome every suggestion, explanation, question or remark about this post.